# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue'

Tags: 2013, spuser, spfielduser

I want to get the user value from the Person or Group column in code behind.

My code is:

```
List<string> manager = GeneralMethods.GetUsers((SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[FieldNames.Manager]);
List<string> owner = GeneralMethods.GetUsers((SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[FieldNames.ProjectOwner]);
```

The method code is:

```
        public static List<string> GetUsers(SPFieldUserValueCollection users)
    {
        List<string> listUsers = new List<string>();

        if (users.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (SPFieldUserValue field in users)
            {
                SPUser user = field.User;
                listUsers.Add(user.LoginName);
            }
        }

        return listUsers;
    }
```

My problem is that `manager` assigned successfully but when the control comes to `owner` then the above mentioned error is thrown. Here the `item[FieldNames.ProjectOwner])` is the person or group column which accepts single value only.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't cast the field directly in a SPFieldUserValueCollection. Try this:

```
public List<string> GetUser(string fieldName, SPListItem item)
{
    List<string> listUsers = new List<string>();
    string strUserColl = item[fieldName].ToString();
    if (strUserColl != null)
    {
        SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, strUserColl);
        if (usercollection != null)
        {
            foreach (SPFieldUserValue userValue in usercollection)
            {
                 SPUser user = userValue.User;
                 listUsers.Add(user.LoginName);
            }
        }
    }
    return listUsers;
}
```

If you want to initialize a SPFieldUserValueCollection object that is bases on a field value, you should use this constructor. See Msdn: [SPFieldUserValueCollection(SPWeb,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms441658.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for reply sir, I tried your way but I am getting error when I call the function.

Comment: what kind of error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that user.LoginName for the project owner returns a string in format ID;#USERACCOUNT. E.g., 34;#domain\user. ID being the Id of the user in this site collection's hidden User Information List.

If it only has a single value, you probably cannot cast it to a collection.

Comment: Error is thrown before executing the method `GetUsers` i.e. error comes when casting

Comment: (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[FieldNames.ProjectOwner] statement throws error

Comment: Updated answer, can it be because you cast single user into SPFieldUserValueCOLLECTION?

Comment: Is there any way to get the single value.?

Comment: It is a single value if the Field is defined to only have single values. You need to cast it to SPFieldUserValue.

Comment: Can you please provide code to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this code a try. I haven't tested it though:

**UPDATE**

Perhaps there is no value in the field. Check for the null condition as shown below:

```
SPFieldUserValue owner = item[FieldNames.ProjectOwner] as SPFieldUserValue;
if (null != owner)
{
   SPUser user = owner.User;
   string ownerLogin = user.LoginName
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggested way but I am getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the line `SPUser user = owner.User;`

Comment: See my updated answer